# Does importing a lot of Custom Labels can slow loading LWC for the first time

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel, import

We have the issue similar ( maybe the same ) to this one :
[Is a big startup delay for the first use of a custom Lightning App ... normal?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348979/is-a-big-startup-delay-for-the-first-use-of-a-custom-lightning-app-using-140-cus)

**The issue :**
When we access **the Custom App** which contains several(15-20) **LWC**'s for **the first time** in the day it takes **a lot of time** to load all LWC's (**20-30 seconds** ).

Interesting that **after** the first load it takes **4-5** seconds to load the page.
As is described in the **question** which I mentioned earlier, the **Apex Methods imports** can cause this long delay.

However my **question** is next :
Can **Custom Labels import** cause this delay ?

```js
import ButtonLabel from '@salesforce/label/ButtonLabel';
```

**One** of my LWC have **30** Custom Labels imports and for all my LWC's the number if Custom Labels imports will be around **100 imports**.

I know that we **can't** import All labels at once, or at least the List of Custom Labels at once.

I **understand** that a lot of things can cause this delay. However it is interesting if the **Custom Labels** imports has a bad impact on the performance ?

**Update :**
I tried to **import 200 Custom Labels** to my **LWC** and [Measure lightning page load times](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000382041&type=1) with **Lightning Debug Mode**.
However I see **no difference** with Custom Labels Imports and without it.

*Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.*

Comment: Did you check the Lightning page analysis to check which LWC takes longer to load ? I build LWCs that has closer to 50 custom labels but didn't notice any performance issues.

Comment: @SLman thanks for a reply. I also did this, I added 200 Custom Labels to my LWC and check it with the Debug Mode and didn't see any difference. I will update my question.